busybox nslookup does not add the .cluster.local suffix automatically - how to fix it?
First, let us have a look at a pod with a "real" nslookup utility:
mark@L-R910LPKW:~$ k -n chip exec deployments/toolbox -- sh -c 'ls -l $(which nslookup) ; nslookup default-redis-redis.system-d-kb-redis.svc'
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        100600 Feb 13  2024 /usr/bin/nslookup
Server:         10.0.0.10
Address:        10.0.0.10#53

Name:   default-redis-redis.system-d-kb-redis.svc.cluster.local
Address: 10.0.6.5

mark@L-R910LPKW:~$

Works as expected.
Now a pod based on the busybox:
mark@L-R910LPKW:~$ k exec deployments/redis-insights-redisinsight -- sh -c 'ls -l $(which nslookup) ; nslookup default-redis-redis.system-d-kb-redis.svc'
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Jun 18 14:16 /usr/bin/nslookup -> /bin/busybox
Server:         10.0.0.10
Address:        10.0.0.10:53

** server can't find default-redis-redis.system-d-kb-redis.svc: NXDOMAIN

** server can't find default-redis-redis.system-d-kb-redis.svc: NXDOMAIN

command terminated with exit code 1
mark@L-R910LPKW:~$

Not sure what to make out of it.
The second pod uses the following image:
mark@L-R910LPKW:~$ k get deployments/redis-insights-redisinsight -o yaml | yq .spec.template.spec.containers[].image
redislabs/redisinsight:2.54.0@sha256:938c50cf95f7389bc93ce4d26e6eed6855736a8e5b5b05f7e640f01d1be2d514
mark@L-R910LPKW:~$

I deploy it using the HELM chart provided by https://truecharts.org
This is not a mere question of nslookup utility. The DNS resolution just does not work as expected on that pod. When the app running there tries to resolve the address of default-redis-redis.system-d-kb-redis.svc it gets back the getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND error.

Since BusyBox's tool set is all custom C code compiled into a single statically-linked binary, it's pretty unlikely that BusyBox nslookup and your application are using the same DNS resolver code.  Do you have a [mcve] describing the Pod that's actually failing at its DNS lookups?

Sure, let me provide an edit to my post.

I have managed to find the root cause. Thank you for your comment.

@mark Instead of editing your question, you should add your solution as an actual answer (which you can then accept). That way, others can learn from your efforts too. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Will do. You are right.

So I tried to reproduce it with the latest busybox image and I could not. I could not even reproduce it with the redis insights image in question (redislabs/redisinsight:2.54.0) as is. However, it does reproduce with the redis insights deployment based on that same image, but originating from the respective HELM chart.
It turns out the deployment contains the following at .spec.template.spec:
dnsConfig:
  options:
  - name: ndots
    value: "1"

I am going to search what this is, but it is the root cause. Once I removed it, the .cluster.local suffix problem disappears.
